# Boost lib missing 'libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-gd-1_44.lib file. How to build only this lib file using bjam?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I need to use the date time functions available in booost/gregorian. When I compile in visual studio 2008 I get the error  `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc90-mt-gd-1_44.lib'`.

I had a look at the lib folder in my system and i found that those files have not been built previously. The question is how do I build only the specific lib files using Bjam? I did see the documentation provided but since I have other necessary lib files I don't intend to rebuild them. Is there a way to do this? Any commands will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly building everything is easy with `bjam`.  Any reason not to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Libraries beginning with libboost are the static version of the boost library, vc90 = VS2008, mt = multi-threaded runtime, gd = debug version:

Try running something like

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-9.0 debug link=static runtime-link=shared install
```

You should be able to run bjam in the directory of boost date time to only build that library. IIRC each directory contains a jam file, but I stand to be corrected.

Of course you may also want to build the release version of the libraries.
In general I think it's a good idea to just build *all* the versions i.e. static, dynamic, debug and release. In my experience this makes it easier for the boost auto-linking in VS to do it's thing.